# Importing global variables in python in two ways

Tags: python, python-3.x

I came across a situation I don't understand. I have three files:

one.py (runnable):

```
import two
import three

three.init()
two.show()
```

two.py:

```
import three

def show():
    print(three.test)
```

three.py:

```
test = 0

def init():
    global test
    test = 1
```

The outcome is 1, as I expected. Now let's modify two.py:

```
from three import test

def show():
    print(test)
```

The outcome is 0. Why?

Comment: because of this `from three import test`.. in 2nd two.py you're importing only `test`, which is equal to `0` in three.py.

Comment: To make a long story short: in the second case, `test` becomes local to `two.py` so rebinding `three.test` doesn't impact `two.test` (these are two different names). For a detailed explanation, read this : https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1):

It's all about scope. 
If you change your one.py as follows you would see better.

```
import three
from three import test

three.init()

print(test)
print(three.test)
```

it will print:

```
0        <== test was imported before init()
1        <== three.test fetches the current value
```

When you import only variable it will create a local variable which is an immutable integer.

But if you change order of the import statement like following you would get a different result:

```
import three

three.init()
print(three.test)

from three import test
print(test)
```

it will print:

```
1        <== three.test fetches the current value
1        <== test was imported after init()
```

Comment: "When you import only variable it will be compiled differently." => this has absolutely nothing to do with compilation, all this happens at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i have fixed that statement.